# How to view content of +DATA, +FRA in RAC environment Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, rman

I am trying to restore oracle RAC RAMN backup to another RAC where only software is installed. I am able to restore control files some how on "`+DATA/...`"

I have some doubt about RAC setup.

Que 1) What are `+DATA`, `+FRA`.

Que 2) I am so curious about exploring +DATA, +FRA ,how can i see content of it in linux?

Que 3)How to change oracle "`+DATA/CDBRAC/ARCHIVELOG/2016_02_20`" archive destination to local storage e.g. "`/u02/archive/2016_02_20`"  during recovery?

because i am not able to `startup mount` because of below failure

```
Oracle instance started
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of startup command at 02/25/2016 15:25:45
ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info
```

I am pretty sure this is because there are no `+DATA/DBRAC/ARCHIVELOG/2016_02_20` path on `+DATA`.

similar problem i was able to resolve in oracle single machine recovery to other location by creating required directory.

Answer (score 0):

`+DATA` and `+FRA` are ASM Disk Groups, you can find out more about them by querying the catalog view `v$asm_diskgroup`.

You can see the contents of ASM Disk Groups with the `asmcmd` utility, e.g.

```
$ amscmd

ASMCMD> cd DATA

ASMCMD> ls
YOURDB1/
YOURDB2/

ASMCMD> cd YOURDB1/

ASMCMD> ls
CONTROLFILE/
DATAFILE/
ONLINELOG/
PARAMETERFILE/
TEMPFILE/
spfileYOURDB1.ora
```

The error you got is related to the control file, you can check the value of the `control_files` parameter with the SQL*Plus command `show parameter control_files`.

Comment: I able to see one record with below query "select GROUP_NUMBER,NAME from v$asm_diskgroup;" as "1 DATA" But not able to see anything on "asmcmd" "ls" command